# How can I update PHP in Google Compute Engine from 5.6?

Tags: php, google-compute-engine

THere's a complete lack of information about Google Compute Engine and upgrading PHP Versions (it all seems to refer to App Engine).

Anyway, I'm running a Wordpress install on php 5.6, and need to upgrade to 7.3.

I can confirm this in the console by `php -v` returning `5.6.17-0+deb8u1 (cli) (build: Jan 13 2016 09:10:12)`

Are there any decent instructions or guidelines on how to properly update this to the latest version of PHP?

Comment: GCE offers you a virtual machine, so, in the end, to update your version, you have to do as you would do with a normal system. What OS are you using?

Comment: I see. In that case, this is coming back as Debian GNU/Linux v8 (Jessie)

Answer (score 5):

GCE offers you a virtual machine, so, in the end, to update your version to the latest of right now (7.3), you have to do as you would do with a normal system.

Since you are using Debian, you can find how to update to the latest PHP version [here](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-7-3-on-debian-9-debian-8/).

1. Update your system with `sudo apt upgrade -y`
2. Add the repository:

`sudo apt -y install lsb-release apt-transport-https ca-certificates`

`sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg`

`echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.3.list`

3. Update and install PHP: `sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install php7.3`

Comment: This worked! But I also had to do a few more things to update MYSQL and get WordPress to to recognize the new version:   `sudo apt-get update`  
sudo apt-get install php7.3-mysql`   and   `sudo a2enmod php7.3`  `sudo a2dismod php7.0`  and then `sudo  systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: Can't stress how important @Dave's comment above is for WordPress to recognize that the php version has been updated. If you do not do `sudo a2dismod php7.0` or whatever version of php you had prior (I had 7.0 before upgrading), WordPress will continue to use the old version.